# How do you compress a list larger than the available memory in Python?

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset

I'm attempting to create a data set to be used in a PyTorch neural network. During image processing, I resize the image to 100x100 pixels, convert the image to a tensor, and append it to the list. Here's the code:

```
data = []
for dir in os.listdir(root):
    for file in tqdm(os.listdir(os.path.join(root, dir))):
        try:
            # images coming in are 1920x1080
            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(root, dir, file), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

            # crop at center to 1080x1080
            img = img[:, 420:1500]

            # downscale to previously decided size 'imsize'
            img = cv2.resize(img, (imsize, imsize))

            # scale pixel values to [-1., 1.]
            img = np.divide(img, np.full((imsize, imsize), 128., dtype=np.float32))
            img = np.subtract(img, np.ones((imsize, imsize)))

            # convert to tensor and append
            tensor = torch.from_numpy(img)
            data.append(tensor)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

torch.save(data, f'{imsize}x{imsize}.pt')
```

The problem is that when I attempt to save the images with decent clarity, the process is killed (I assume due to a lack of memory).

I need ~26GB of image tensors to load into PyTorch's `DataLoader`. Is there a better way to do this? Would it be better to buffer the data? Should I create multiple shuffled sets and run through a training loop for each dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Create batches of the dataset rather than attempting to process it all at once.

```
for batch in range(batches):
    data = []
    for dir in os.listdir(root):
        for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(root, dir)):
            begin = batch_size * batch

            # files stored in '000.png' format
            if int(file[:-4]) in range(begin, begin + batch_size):
                img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(root, dir, file), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                
                # manipulate image

                tensor = torch.from_numpy(img)
                data.append(tensor)

    torch.save(data, f'batch{batch}-{imsize}x{imsize}.pt')
```

Then when training, run through all epochs for each batch of data individually, building on the model each time.

Comment: This saves to 4.7GB per batch where a batch contains 500 images at 1080x1080 float32 pixels.